# Unable to retrieve Worksheets from a spreadsheet using google spreadsheets api

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm getting the error "com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Unauthorized" when I try to retrieve the worksheets from a particular spreadsheet. I'm using the same code that has been given in "https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#audience" but still I'm getting the error.

Below is the code:

public class SpreadsheetApiQuickstart {

```
  private static final String SCOPE = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full";

  private static final String APP_NAME = "S.A.R.A.H";
 authorized user.

  private static final String USER = "me";

  private static final String CLIENT_SECRET_PATH = "C://Users/ahrashid.contractor/Downloads/client_secret_461052169747-ffbpdvcbmu822r2vg2bhrn4ae3lrjri8.apps.googleusercontent.com.json";

  private static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ServiceException {
     HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,  new FileReader(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH));
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Arrays.asList(SCOPE))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setApprovalPrompt("force").build();

            String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI)
                .build();
            System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type"
                               + " the authorization code:\n" + url);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String code = br.readLine();

            // Generate Credential using retrieved code.
            GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(GoogleOAuthConstants.OOB_REDIRECT_URI).execute();


            GoogleCredential credential = new                      GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setClientSecrets(clientSecrets).build().setFromTokenResponse(response);


     SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(APP_NAME);
            service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);

        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

            if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
              // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
            }

            // TODO: Choose a spreadsheet more intelligently based on your
            // app's needs.
            SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
            System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

            // Make a request to the API to fetch information about all
            // worksheets in the spreadsheet.

    /* Till here everything is working fine. I'm getting the exception in the below line */

            List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = spreadsheet.getWorksheets(); /* this line gives com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Unauthorized exception" */

            // Iterate through each worksheet in the spreadsheet.
            for (WorksheetEntry worksheet : worksheets) {
              // Get the worksheet's title, row count, and column count.
              String title = worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText();
              int rowCount = worksheet.getRowCount();
              int colCount = worksheet.getColCount();

              // Print the fetched information to the screen for this worksheet.
              System.out.println("\t" + title + "- rows:" + rowCount + " cols: " + colCount);
```

}

Comment: I set the token in the header  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964711/authorizing-requests-with-oauth-2-0-in-google-spreadsheet-api/14096564#14096564 rather than using service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential); --- Also, tokens expire after 1 hour.