# How to perform 0Auth2.0 authorization for Google Spreadsheet API for android?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, authorization, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use Google spreadsheet API so that I can directly edit and retrieve data from an online google sheet. I tried reading the guide at 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize but I am stuck at the authorize requests part. It only provides the demo code for .NET but not java. It says to perform a OAuth 2.0. How do I do that? I tried going into developer console but can't seem to find the API for google spreadsheet.

Comment: You may want to check [question 7964711](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964711/authorizing-requests-with-oauth-2-0-in-google-spreadsheet-api?rq=1). It provides useful links and information as to how you can authorize Google APIs using OAuth2.0.